# Conditioning the records to be related in a recursive relation

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model as the below that have a recursive relation with it self:

```py
class Unit(models.Model):

    unit_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False, unique=True)

    is_main_unit = models.BooleanField(blank=False, default=False)

    main_unit = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.unit_name
```

This one is working as I want except by that I need that ONLY objects (records in the table) that are "main" (`is_main_unit=True`) have related others units.

In other words -and functionality talking- in the admin screen- when I am adding an non main unit, I need that only main units will displayed in the list box to be selected and related to the no main unit that is being created.

I am trying to use the `related_name` and `related_query_name` attributes but I can't found the way to reach the expected behavior.

I tried and play with the bellow code, but I don't know how to define the condition `is_main_unit=True` in the relation definition:

```
class Unit(models.Model):

    ...

    main_unit = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True,related_name='unidades_asociadas',related_query_name='unidades_principales')

    ...
```

Regards and thanks in advance ...
Homero Matus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want [the `limit_choices_to` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to):

```
main_unit = models.ForeignKey(
    'self', 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    limit_choices_to={"is_main_unit": True},
    )
```

> I am trying to use the 'related_name' and 'related_query_name' attributes

That's not what they are for.

Comment: Awesome doc ! Was fine.   
And syntax code simply and clear.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @hmatus glad I could help (and feel free to accept  the answer if it solved your issue BTW) - but the credits for the doc quality and syntax should go to the Django team, really ;-)

Comment: off course doc.
The credits by the solution, are yours @bruno and the django team (as your say)
;-)
Thanks again and best regards !